# loading ontology from document takes too much time and uses all my memory space

Tags: java, semantic-web, ontology, owl

I am trying to load an ontology in java using the org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument method.
When I run the code, it takes about one minute until the ontology is loaded, and it sometimes results in an out of memory error.
I guess the reason is that the ontology is pretty large.
Is there any way to solve this?
Perhaps only load the essential part of the ontology?

The code looks like this:

```
String prefix = "http://localhost:8888/ontologies/myOntology.owl#"
iri = IRI.create(prefix);
ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(iri);
```

Comment: Are you loading a huge file?

Comment: I edited the question and added the code part. The file I'm loading is pretty huge I guess, It's an ontology with about 200 classes.

Comment: Split the file into smaller ones and then load each file to database. Otherwise loading and building the model will run out of memory.

Comment: The ontology I'm trying to load is a merged version of three other ontologies. But even when I'm trying to load the ontologies apart I get the OutOfMemoryError. When trying to terminate the process in Eclipse he says 'terminate failed' and I have to stop the java process in activity window manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself.
I still don't know the exact reason, but somehow the problem is caused by performing this code multithreaded and not by loading the ontology itself. When I run the code without multithreading, the loading only takes several seconds

Answer (score 2):

Your ontology is not that big (if 200 classes - big ones according to literature have over 300'000 classes) and you shouldn't encounter any memory problem using the OWL-API on modern machine (at least 2 Go of memory).

How to solve the issue:

- Make sure the JVM has enough memory allocated to it: Use the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` flags.
- Load the file from the system (example `/home/foo/bar.owl`) rather than from `localhost` proxy.
- You mentioned thread problems: Make sure only one thread reads the file at a time. The API takes care of threading the reading for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the slowness is inevitable if you are loading a huge ontology, but you can try and increase the memory allocated to Java as shown [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7) so that at least you know the ontology will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing the problem only when running the code in a multithreaded environment, there is a chance you stumbled upon some OWL API bugs in that respect, in the past this has been caused by HashMaps used as caches in various places and causing threads to get stuck if a change to the map happens at the same time as a read access.

200 classes is a fairly small ontology, so it should take seconds. If you can reproduce this situation consistently, please report it as a bug on github or on the OWLAPI mailing list.